# Does perf includes some "graphing" abilities?

Tags: linux-kernel, profiling, perf

It's possible to create a bitmap or a vector image out of the data collected by the `perf` profiler under linux ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what part of the output of `perf` would you like to plot? It should be doable to parse it and pipe into gnuplot or other plotting utility.

Comment: @Ketan I'm interested in multithreading and profiling the applications that work that way, so I would like to show, Cache misses, Percentage of branching, Memory usage, and so on. Mostly something about the CPU and a little bit about memory. But I would like to see some tutorial about that "piping", maybe I could adapt that to my needs.

Comment: Can you add the actual `perf` command(s) you're attempting to use. It's a pretty versatile tool and there are many directions to go here.

Comment: @user2485710 There are many nice commandlines demonstrating piping and gnuplot on commandlinefu.com, one example is: `history | awk '{a[$2]++}END{for(i in a){print a[i] " " i}}' | sort -rn | head > /tmp/cmds | gnuplot -persist <(echo 'plot "/tmp/cmds" using 1:xticlabels(2) with boxes')` which will plot the most frequently used commands from history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this article titled: [perf Examples](http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html), it has a number of examples that show how you can make flame graphs such as this one:

[image: flamegraph]

The above graph can be generated as an interactive SVG file as well. The graph was generated using the [FlameGraph tool](https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph). This is separate software from `perf`.

A series of commands similar to this were used to generate that graph:

```
$ perf record -a -g -F 99 sleep 60
$ perf script | ./stackcollapse-perf.pl > out.perf-folded
$ ./flamegraph.pl out.perf-folded > perf-kernel.svg
```

The CPU FlameGraphs (above) are covered in more detail in this article, titled: [CPU Flame Graphs](http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpuflamegraphs). For details on FlameGraphs for other resources such as memory check out this page titled: [Flame Graphs](http://www.brendangregg.com/flamegraphs.html).

Comment: it really looks like an ugly graph, it works, but it's less readable than what I would like it to be

Comment: I would prefer a simple histogram or a simple chart with 2 dimensions ( 1 on x and 1 on y ) to this; the important thing is that it should be easy to read and less chaotic .

Comment: @user2485710 - I'm not finding a lot of tools that you can graph the perf data with. The FlameGraphs is by far the most feature rich and capable. The only other thing I found was `perf report --gtk perf.data` but that is pretty weak in comparison.